Loading videos one after the other freezes PHP website
I have a PHP website hosted from my Raspberry Pi 4 8GB RAM using Apache2. It's just a website that shows the time while playing videos in the back. The videos are stored on the Pi, not on the client.
I have a video element in my index.php file with an onended event bound function which gets the next video file path (e.g. /Media/video_name.mp4) stored in an array inside my JavaScript file. It then sets the video element's source (src) to new new source.
However, after a while of running and changing the video source many times, the entire website freezes. The clock text does not change anymore. The video is eithe`r stuck or completely white (freezes between video loading I guess). This happens when running the website on the Pi as well as on my PC. I'm starting to think it's something related to memory cache or the video element itself.
I'm always running my website using the url "https://website/index.php" even on the server itself (instead of using localhost).
Also, I have the net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error because I have an invalid certificate for my HTTPS website. Perhaps this is related?
I spotted this problem after updating my website to use PHP and HTTPS. My index.html became index.php. I also generated a personal certificate for my HTTPS that is "not trusted" which gives me a warning whenever I access the website.
Here is the code I was using to make tests to see what caused the crash. This code only displays videos which causes the freeze after running for an hour using short videos and after 12 hours for longer videos.
index.php:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body id="body" onload="onLoad()">
    <video autoplay muted id="myVideo" class="myMedia" onended="NextMedia()">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
    <img id="myGIF" class="myMedia" onload="onImageLoaded()" onerror="onImageError()" />

    <div class="dateTimePanel">
        <b id="time_txt">00:00:00</b>
        <div id="date_txt">1 January 2000</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tittleSection">
        <div id="video_name">VIDEO NAME HERE</div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>

script.js:
const video_list = [
    ["dog.mp4", "cat.mp4", "bird.mp4", "hamster.mp4"]
    , ["tokyo.mp4", "berlin.mp4", "france.mp4", "london.mp4"]
    , ["gif 1.gif", "gif 2.mp4", "gif 3.gif", "gif 4.gif"]
];
const dir_paths = ["./animals/", "./cities/", "./gifs/"];

const weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var clockTimer;
var videoTimeout;

var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var GIF = document.getElementById("myGIF");
var media_title = document.getElementById('video_name');
var video_index = 0;
var playlist_index = 0;

function onLoad() {
    startTime();
    shuffle(video_list[0]);
    video.loop = false;
    NextMedia();
};

function NextMedia() {
    video_index++;
    if (video_index >= video_list[0].length) {
        video_index = 0;
        shuffle(video_list[0]);
    }
    media_src = dir_paths[0].concat(video_list[0][video_index]);
    document.getElementById('video_name').innerHTML = media_src;
    setMediaVisibility(media_src);
    // Sets the video name text
    media_title.innerHTML = video_list[0][video_index];
}

function setMediaVisibility(media_src) {
    video.style.visibility = "collapse";
    GIF.style.visibility = "collapse";
    // Verify if the file is a video
    if (media_src.toLowerCase().substr(media_src.length - 4).localeCompare("webm") == 0
        || media_src.toLowerCase().substr(media_src.length - 3).localeCompare("mp4") == 0
        || media_src.toLowerCase().substr(media_src.length - 3).localeCompare("mov") == 0
        || media_src.toLowerCase().substr(media_src.length - 3).localeCompare("avi") == 0) {
        video.style.visibility = "visible";
        video.src = media_src;
        video.play();
    }
    if (media_src.toLowerCase().substr(media_src.length - 3).localeCompare("gif") == 0
        || media_src.toLowerCase().substr(media_src.length - 3).localeCompare("jpg") == 0
        || media_src.toLowerCase().substr(media_src.length - 4).localeCompare("jpeg") == 0
        || media_src.toLowerCase().substr(media_src.length - 4).localeCompare("webp") == 0) {
        GIF.style.visibility = "visible";
        GIF.src = media_src;
    }
}

function getPlaylist() {
    return video_list[playlist_index];
}

function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle.
    while (currentIndex != 0) {

        // Pick a remaining element.
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex--;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
            array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
    }

    return array;
};

function startTime() {
    clearTimeout(clockTimer);
    const today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    var day = weekday[today.getDay()];
    var date = today.getDate();
    var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    h = checkTime(h);
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    date = checkTime(date);
    month = checkTime(month);

    document.getElementById('time_txt').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    document.getElementById('date_txt').innerHTML = day + " " + year + "/" + month + "/" + date;
    clockTimer = setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
};

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
};

I tried to set the video's src to "" then call video.load() to clear any memory used. I also added the video.load() call after whenever I set my video's src.
I tried running my website with the bare minimum for the video (no clocks, no playlists) and it works for at least 12 hours when it comes to GIFs (using a img element). It also worked for longer videos (3-5 minutes) because I'm not changing the video src as much I guess.
I'm aiming to make my website work 24/7 without the need to go through the "untrusted certificate warning" and without it freezing.
I have only tested my program using PHP because I transitioned from HTML to PHP without changing my HTML (or PHP in this case) or my JavaScript code. Right after the transition, the problem started to appear. Therefore, I assumed it was regarding PHP and did not investigate further with a regular HTML file. The website freezes on my PC while the server is running on my Pi. I can still operate my Pi while the website on my PC is frozen.
I've also tried the answer on the following thread but to no avail. Same result: How do i change the src of an html5 video via javascript without either crashing chrome or leak memory?
The browser on my PC is Chrome Version 130.0.6723.117 running on Windows 11 Home Build 22621.4317. The browser on my Raspberry Pi 4 8 GB RAM is Chromium (latest) running on Raspbian Release 11 uname 6.1.21-v8+. The browser "freezes" as in any action I do does not do anything on the browser. A warning on Chromium indicates that the page is unresponsive and asks if I want to close the page which does not do anything. I have to ALT+F4 and reopen the page in order to get the website running again. When it freezes on my PI, the server is still responsive and can be accessed from my PC.
Because the Pi takes less time for Chromium to freeze, I have logged the CPU and MEM usage of chromium from start to freeze on Raspbian. Here's the data:
Data on launch: S | 173.8% CPU | 2.6% MEM | 2:05.97 TIME+ | Chromium-Browser



Time
CPU%
MEM%




10h04
37.0
2.2


10h14
168.9
2.8


10h26
203.0
2.9


10h34
136.2
3.2


10h55
172.1
2.2


11h04
62.3
2.6


11h10 [F]
FREEZE
FREEZE


11h20
53.6
3.4



The browser froze at 11h10. I logged the final data 10 minutes after the freeze.
Update
I tried passing the video source through the URL (thus "changing webpage") instead of changing my video's source after having another source. This method did not fix my problem and the website still became unresponsive after a while.
I also tried running the website "locally". I ran it as a simple html file in my browser instead of through Apache and the website still freezes. Therefore it might not be related to Apache or my HTTPS nor PHP setup. I guess the bug was always there and I noticed it at that point by coincidence.
